# Unable to Create Device Set at Library/Developer/XCPGDevices

Tags: xcode, xcode8, swift-playground

I'm using Xcode 8 and cannot run a playground.  As soon as the playground opens and starts to build the file I get this error:

[image: Xcode Playground Error]

Under Preferences -> Components in Xcode I do not see any iOS 10 Simulators available for install:

[image: Components]

I have Xcode 6.4, 7.3, and 8.0 installed but my command line tools are pointing to Xcode 8.  How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restarting my computer and opening Xcode 8 before 7 or 6 fixed this error and made Xcode 8 playgrounds start working again.

Comment: Why do I _always_ forget this step? Should I get checked for amnesia?

Comment: Seems to work even without restarting, so long as you close all Xcodes and re-open just the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quit all Xcode versions you have running. Quit the simulators as well.
2. Then open the desired Xcode version.
3. Go to Xcode >> Preferences >> Locations >> Command Line Tools >> and change it to match the Xcode version you've just selected. **You have to do this manually each time you switch between different Xcode versions!** To be on the safe side just delete the derived data as well. But I'm usually able to get it to work without that.
4. If that didn't work then also restart your mac.